# Parse json response to get parent/child dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, testrail

I have a list of jsons (that's originally response from [TestRail API getcases](http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/reference-cases)) which I'm trying to parse. Here's a sample json:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": null,
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "parent_id": null,
},
{
    "id": 16,
    "parent_id": 2,
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "parent_id": 1,
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 6
}
]
```

What I wanna do is to figure out what Ids fall under original parent ID.
for example `id:1` and `"id": 6,` are the most top level parent nodes since `"parent_id": null` for them.

I want to get all the child nodes fall under the top most parents.
In this example here's the relationships based on the `parent_id`

1 -> [2,7] -> 16

6 -> 3

The main goal is to determine what are all the child (and subchild) nodes for a top-level parent node. I'm not interested in knowing sub-parent/subchild rellationships.

what I want to parse is to get the following output:

```
{
 1: [2,7,16],
 6: 3
}
```

One approach is to go with a couple of nested for loops , for each top-parent node check if that's presented as `parent_id` and go with that recursively, but that doesn't look like a very good approach.

would appreciate any comments/suggestions

Comment: read all nodes, add them as connections to a graph, then do a bfs/dfs from each node that has no parent to know all the nodes it can reach

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

from collections import defaultdict

data = json.loads(
    '[{"id": 1, "parent_id": null}, {"id": 2, "parent_id": 1}, {"id": 6, "parent_id": null}, {"id": 16, "parent_id": 2}, {"id": 7, "parent_id": 1}, {"id": 3, "parent_id": 6}]')

parents = {d['id']: d['parent_id'] for d in data}

class RootsDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        parent = parents[key]
        if parent is None:
            return key
        else:
            return self[parent]

roots_dict = RootsDict()
descendants = defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    id_ = d['id']
    if d['parent_id'] is not None:
        descendants[roots_dict[id_]].append(id_)

print(descendants)  # {1: [2, 16, 7], 6: [3]}
```

`roots_dict` is designed so that `roots_dict[node]` will return the top level parent of `node`, or `node` itself if it's already a root. `__missing__` is a special method that can be overridden for dicts. It's called when `key` is requested from the dict but isn't present. Whatever the method returns will then be placed in the dict at that value. So for example `roots_dict[16]` when first accessed will be set to equal `roots_dict[2]`, which in turn will ask for `roots_dict[1]`, which is just `1`. The rest is pretty straightforward.